# How can I prove that the antiderivative of $x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that 
$x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is continuous and therefore for all $\Bbb R$ except 0 where the function is undefined.
It seems to be pretty hard to compute the exact value of the antiderivative.

Comment: Not so hard, here's one antiderivative: $F(x)=\int_0^x y^2 \sin\frac{1}{y}\, dy$. Are you sure it is not enough for your purposes?

Comment: Do you want to prove it exists or do you want something else? It exists because the function is continous (upon completion by 0 at 0) and every cont; function has an antiderivative. .

Comment: I have to show a function which isn't continuous and which has an antiderivative. I could prove that the function isn't continuous at $x=0$, but I don't know what should I exactly write about the antiderivative.

Comment: Your function is not really an example of that as the singularity is removable. If you want to do what you said, I would propose you start with a function that is differentiable but whose derivative is not continous. This function is then clearly the antiderivative of that non-cont function. In fact the function you have is just such a function. If you set it 0 at 0, you can show it is differentiable everywhere, but its derivative is not contnous at 0. Thus you function is an example for an anti-detivative of a non-cont function. So determine the derivative (not anti der) of your function.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. Where it is defined, you may perform the change of variable, $u=1/x$, $dx=-du/u^2$, giving
$$
\int x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=-\int \frac1{u^4} \sin u\: du
$$
then one may successively integrate by parts :
$$
\begin{align}
-\int \frac1{u^4} \sin u\: du&=\frac1{3u^3}\sin u-\frac13\int\frac1{u^3}\cos u \: du\\\\
&=\frac1{3u^3}\sin u-\frac13\left(-\frac1{2u^2}\cos u-\frac12\int\frac1{u^2}\sin u \: du\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{3u^3}\sin u+\frac16\frac1{u^2}\cos u+\frac16\left(-\frac{\sin u}u+\int\frac{\cos u}u \: du\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{3u^3}\sin u+\frac16\frac1{u^2}\cos u-\frac16\frac{\sin u}u+\frac16\text{CosIntegral}(u)
\end{align}
$$ or

> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\int x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\\\
> &=\frac{1}{3} x^3 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{6} x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{6} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac16 \text{CosIntegral}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+C
> \end{align}
> $$

where we have used the [$\text{CosIntegral}(\cdot)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)  function.

Comment: Given the comments this will not help OP at all. But well I suppose it answers the question as written.

Comment: @quid I was busy typing my answer and did not read the comments :) Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense. Sometimes the site is so quick one loses track easily.